# incompatible type with Int array in C

Tags: c, arrays, incomplete-type

I'm just learning C, and I'm having problems assigning an array to a globally defined array in a function:

```
// So I have my multi-dim global array
uint16_t pulseSets[1][50][2];

void foo()
{
   //create another array to work with in here
   uint16_t pulses[50][2];

   // Do some stuff with pulses here
   // ...

   // and now assign it to my global array
   pulseSets[0] = pulses;

}
```

When compiling I get the error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type ‘uint16_t[50][2]’ from type
>   ‘uint16_t (*)[2]’
>
> ```
>  pulseSets[0] = pulses;
>               ^
> ```

Both arrays are of the same type and size, so why is this breaking?

Answer (score 1):

Why it's breaking, it's because 'pulses' is considered a pointer (missing []).

A way around it would be to use a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
  uint16_t Pulses[ 50 ][ 2 ];
} Pulse;

Pulse pulseSets[ 2 ];

void foo()
{
   //create another array to work with in here
   Pulse pulses;

   // Do some stuff with pulses here
   // ...
   memset( pulses, 0, sizeof(pulses));

   // and now assign it to my global array
   pulseSets[ 0 ] = pulses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, array memory allocations are treated as constant pointers and cannot be re-assigned after their creation.

Thus, your global declaration `uint16_t pulseSets[1][50][2];` created `100 ints` that `pulseSets[0]` points to, but `pulseSets[0]` cannot be reset to point at some other location in memory.

You have 2 options:
1. copy the data from `pulses[50][2]` to `pulseSets[0]` in a nested for loop (which involves 100 int copies)
2. declare your global pulseSets[1][50][2] as a pointer to the two-dimensional array and use dynamic memory allocation in foo() to assign to it as such:

```
int **pulseSets[2];

void foo()
{
   //create another array to work with in here
    int **pulses = new int[50][];
    for (int i = 0;i<50;i++)
        pulses[i] = new int[2];

   // Do some stuff with pulses here
   // ...

   // and now assign it to my global array

   pulseSets[0] = pulses;
}
```